# Unity scroll bar not working across levels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scrollbar

I have a help menu in each level which can be opened when player pauses the game. The screenshots below shows my setup of the scroll rect and the scroll bar.[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

The scrollbar works works perfectly on `level x`, but it stops working on `level x+1`. I have tried resetting the visibility in the Scroll Rect to Permanent, but it is quite buggy. Sometimes the scroll works sometimes it doesn't. What is causing this stupid behaviour?

ResetScrollBar script is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ResetScrollBar : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnEnable()
    {
        StartCoroutine(resetScrollPos());
    }

    public void resetScroll()
    {
        StartCoroutine(resetScrollPos());
    }

    IEnumerator resetScrollPos()
    {
        yield return null; // Waiting just one frame is probably good enough, yield return null does that
        gameObject.GetComponent<Scrollbar>().value = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you changing levels?

Comment: We need to know exactly how you are changing levels, and the persistence - if any of the GameObjects in the scene. Have you tried testing this in a build?

Comment: @Draco18s I am changing it using `SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);`

Comment: @JaredMerritt, there is another gameobject called `Game Session` which persists across levels using `DontDestroyOnLoad`, but this gameobject is destroyed on every level.

Comment: What does your `ResetScrollBar` script do?

Comment: @AlexMyers I have attached the script as well. I am using it to reset the scrollbar position because it was setting up in the middle always. I checked if it is being called multiple times to cause this issue. But the script is not a problem in anyway.

Comment: try a yield return new waitForSeconds(0.2f); instead of null. some little delay might help, also if the GO is destroyed on every level you shouldn't need to reset its values.

Comment: @comphonia I don't know why it was happening, but without reset the scrollbar was starting in the middle instead of the top everytime. So I had to hard reset it.